# how to let commands operate in sequence where first command opens a separate shell

Tags: bash, shell

Haven't written program for quite long time, I am scratching my head for this one.  I did some research first but nothing I find seems working in my case so far.  So here's my task:

1) First command:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
```

which will open a separate shell(not sure if it's the correct terminology to called it shell yet that's what comes in to my mind) and output as follow'

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-49-138:~/script$ openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1866227133 zmydXvw5oa7oYxVcuSDr
```

2) now enter the 2nd command: EHLO ip-172-31-49-138

which yields the following output --

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-49-138:~/script$ openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1866227133 zmydXvw5oa7oYxVcuSDr
EHLO ip-172-31-49-138
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
```

so I need to write a bash script to automate those two commands(there're more commands but for simplicity I only list the first two).

no matter I use &, or grouping {}, or insert enter line, the script will always execute the first command first, which seems waiting for something until time out, then called the 2nd command at which point the system will not recognize it because it only available while still in the shell bring up by the first command:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-49-138:~/script$ ./sendMail
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1866227133 CuOz95oNth2yafnNOxp4
421 Timeout waiting for data from client.
./sendMail: line 3: EHLO: command not found
bitnami@ip-172-31-49-138:~/script$
```

Hope someone can shed some light into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second "command" isn't a command at all - it's input to your first command. As such, you need to pipe it in. The following will work:

```
echo EHLO ip-172-31-49-138 | openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
```

Comment: Hi Joseph:  Bingo! Thx for the tip and it works.  While my first concern is well addressed, now it get to my next question: what to do if I have more input to the commands.  For example, I tried "AUTH LOGIN | echo EHLO ip-172-31-49-138 | openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465" yet it did not work.  I have about 10 more inputs following the first command.

Comment: Put them all inside of a here document: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: Wow, heredoc is the solvent.  Thanks for the great help!